# Are there anyways to write an integer to a file in MIPS?

Tags: mips

I had an assignment and I almost completed. But I found it tough to write integer to a file in MIPS. Are there anyways to write Int to a file in MIPS?

Comment: If you're talking about MARS or QtSpim, then, no.  printing integers only works to console.  Will need to create a string from integer and print string to file, and, there's no print to string either, so you'll need your own `itoa`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. For example, if your integer is `0x31313131`, do you want the file to contain "1111" or "31313131" after the write?